# IntelliJ clean import Hybris project

Tags: intellij-idea, import, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to (re)import a hybris project in IntelliJ with the hybris integration plugin. But every time when I get to the point to select the modules there are none except the project name itself. If I try to ignore that and just press next than I end up with a project without folder / modules.

That problem came after I imported that project ones and then deleted all files that are pointed to IntelliJ.

Is it possible to clean IntelliJ from a whole project with all dependencies etc. so I can import the project like nothing happend before?

Comment: What is the plugin? Can you try this : Go to File->Import Module and import the project using Import module from external model option and choose eclipse.

Comment: it's the normal hybris plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7525-hybris-integration), it formats the folder view in modules for better workflow

Comment: I just tried to import as an eclipse project and it finds all modules (I guess). then I tried to reimport as a hybris project and I get the same problem (no modules, except of the project name itself) again

Comment: Don't use the plugin then, it's only a source of error... Actually I used to use the hybris plugin on Eclipse but I removed it since it make Eclipse bug a lot. Only Eclipse is referenced properly in hybris doc. If the Eclipse plugin is buggy you imagine the quality of an intelliJ plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 5.4.2 is broken. Downgrading to the older one (5.3.1) worked for me and fixed that "no modules when importing"-problem

Answer (score 3):

v5.4.2 required other plugins which you probably had disabled. such as spring, ant or git.

The best way to get speedy resolution on the intellij hybris plugin is from their jira support portal. Dont forget to register/login first so that you can get an answer.

https://hybris-integration.atlassian.net